# How to completly bind a ComboBox in a JSON View

Tags: view, model, sapui5

Im trying to bind a complete ComboBox with a template in a JSON View. I bind the model to the view and it is no problem to bind it with a template which i create in the controller. But how can i achieve this only in the view?

I oriented myself on this example, which is using xml views: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3689278

I had to mask and condense the code, so maybe the view isnt working correctly in this form
Here is my (condensed) View:

```
{
"Type": "sap.ui.core.mvc.JSONView",
"controllerName": "appname.controller.controllerName",
"height": "100%",
"width": "100%",
"content": [
    {
        "Type": "sap.m.Page",
        "title": "Suche",
        "content": [
            {
                "Type": "sap.ui.commons.ComboBox",
                "id": "myCbo",
                "maxPopupItems": 5,
                "items": {
                    "path": "{ModelName>ItemsForMyCbo}",
                    "template": {
                        "Type": "sap.ui.core.ListItem"
                        "text": "{Value}",
                        "key": "{Key}",
                        "enabled": true,
                        "icon": "",
                        "additionalText": "",
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Here is my Model:

```
screenModel : {

        ItemsForMyCbo : [
            {
                Key : "1",
                Value : "Val1"
            },
            {
                Key : "2",
                Value : "Val2"
            },
            {
                Key : "3",
                Value : "Val3"
            }
        ]
    }
```

And the part of the controller:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel()
    oModel.setData(this.screenModel);

    this.getView().setModel(oModel, "ModelName");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to bind the complete combobox

```
{
"items": {
    "path": "ModelName>/ItemsForMyCbo",
    "template": {
        "Type": "sap.ui.core.ListItem",
        "text": "{ModelName>Value}",
        "key": "{ModelName>Key}"
    }
},
"Type": "sap.ui.commons.ComboBox",
"width": "150px",
"id": "myCbo"
}
```

Its somewhat confusing to use the binding (braces) for the template properties but not for the combobox path property

Comment: It's not that confusing... The property is already called `path`, so the API is expecting a proper path and not some stuff written between curly brackets. But in XML views you only have plain strings, no `path` property (well you can also use path in XML views, but thats another story). So they came up with the curly brackets to distinguish between paths and basic strings. Sounds straightforward to me.

Answer (score 3):

Your bindings need the following adjustments. Please refer also to the [development guide](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d52e364907f94a3caeb4f5e5ad0cf302.html) to understand the binding syntax.

```
"items": {
    "path": "ModelName>/ItemsForMyCbo",
    "template": {
        "Type": "sap.ui.core.ListItem"
        "text": "{ModelName>Value}",
        "key": "{ModelName>Key}",
        "enabled": true,
        "icon": "",
        "additionalText": "",
    }
```

}

Comment: thx for your effort, but you use your binding wrong. In the path-property the binding syntax is "ignored". I assume the path property is already in the binding-context and you dont have to use the braces. Have a look at my Answer

Comment: I fixed the answer. It's an old habit as I only use XML views where you use curly brackets everywhere.

Comment: and thats the problem, in the documentation and in the example are always xml views. So its kind of try and error to translate xml to json